# how to make subplots using user defined function

Tags: matplotlib, data-science

[image]

Can some one help me,i have created one function which can plot scatter plot.If I chnage the agruments in function ,i get different subplots.Now,How can i put this function so that i can put in subplots changing different arguments.

I tried to put function in subplots, but  throws error

Comment: Since [ask] specifically says not to use screenshots of code, please [edit] your question with the code and stack trace as text.

Comment: The way matplotlib works, your user-defined function needs a parameter `ax` on which to plot.